# The Stone 7:4: Letterhead

Tags: the-stone

Thank you for your help on the other puzzle from the stone

I am now working on "7:4 Letterhead" ( http://www.scarecrowsfield.com/)

I have one "close" (pretty obvious) and have tried a gazillion answers but I think I'm completely "out"

Anyone can provide me a nudge on this one?

Comment: The link here in your question is giving me a database error; did you paste it incorrectly? Also, if you solved it, could you please post your solution here as an answer? :)

Comment: i have changed the url to the root url. i can not post the solution but i can post a nudge (a hint)

Comment: If you've solved it I would recommend answering this question and marking that as the chosen answer.

Comment: Isn't this 7:4?  According to my records, 7:9 is Bunches.

Comment: @Teryx OOPS! thanks grin I was so much in the letters that i went wrong in the numbers i guess lol

Comment: @edelwater: I edited your question to remove the "updated" bits. If you need to update your question, feel free to just simply edit it. You don't need to keep a changelog in the question body because the site keeps a history of the edits made. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "I like the people who made The
>   Beginning of the End"

p.s. I have no idea why someone downvoted my answer. To clarify: The Stone Game prohibits of giving players direct answers, hints are called nudges, this has been the case for the past N years. The great fun is finding a solution yourself with possible hints if you are going insane :) This is my nudge to this puzzle, if you are in need of more help , just comment!